# expand a series, then fill remaining columns

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am trying to expand a series contained in part of a dataframe and repeat the values in the remaining columns to fill in the new rows. I have a grouping variable that I need to use, and then recombine to have a single dataframe again. Here's an example of what I mean, and how I'd do it piece-wise:

```
df <- data.frame("group" = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3)), val=rep(c(1,3,5),2))
values <- data.frame(val=seq(1:5))

df2.a <- df[df$group=="A",]
df3.a <- right_join(df2.a, values, "val")
df3.a$group <- "A"

df2.b <- df[df$group=="B",]
df3.b <- right_join(df2.b, values, "val")
df3.b$group <- "B"

df4 <- rbind(df3.a, df3.b)
```

Here, `df4` is my desired output.

But I'm sure I can be way more efficient using `dplyr` or some other split-apply-combine approach, though I'm clearly missing something.

Conceptually, this makes sense to me:

```
df.interp <- df %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  full_join(x=., y=values, by="val") %>%
  fill(group)
```

Though I can't complete the last line here because I can't edit the grouping variable. But if I `ungroup`, then I'm no longer operating on one group at a time, and I fill the new rows (which there aren't enough of) with the wrong value.

I'm sure I'm missing something simple here...what is it?

Comment: You probably want `tidyr::complete`, possibly in combination with `nesting`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  complete(val = min(val):max(val))

# # A tibble: 10 x 2
# # Groups:   group [2]
#    group   val
#    <fct> <dbl>
# 1  A         1
# 2  A         2
# 3  A         3
# 4  A         4
# 5  A         5
# 6  B         1
# 7  B         2
# 8  B         3
# 9  B         4
# 10 B         5
```

Comment: @markus it depends on what you need, right? Anyway, I didn't use `seq_len` so the minimum can be manipulated easily. Cheers.

Comment: And in actual problem, `val` doesn't start at 1 and isn't necessarily consistent, so I've replaced that with `val = min(val):max(val)`. Thanks for the simple solution! I knew it existed...

Answer (score 2):

Adding a `data.table` option.

Define a helper function

```
f <- function(x) {
  tmp <- range(x)
  tmp[1]:tmp[2]
}
```

Apply `f` by group

```
library(data.table)
out <- setDT(df)[, .(val = f(val)), by=group]
out
#    group val
# 1:     A   1
# 2:     A   2
# 3:     A   3
# 4:     A   4
# 5:     A   5
# 6:     B   1
# 7:     B   2
# 8:     B   3
# 9:     B   4
#10:     B   5
```

Comment: Nice one +1, but why not ```setDT(df)[, .(val = min(val):max(val)), .(group)]```?

Comment: @M-- I remembered reading somewhere that using `range` is a little safer. Probably doesn't matter in OP's case. Also I wanted to show an alternative to `min(val):max(val)`

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how the actual data is but can there be cases where a particular group max is not same as the max in `values$val` ? So for example, in this case what if there is no 3rd row in `df` with 5 ? Do we still need `A` group to have rows till 5? If that can be the case we can complete our sequence from `values` dataframe.

Using `tidyr::crossing`

```
tidyr::crossing(df %>% select(group), values)

# A tibble: 10 x 2
#   group   val
#   <fct> <int>
# 1 A         1
# 2 A         2
# 3 A         3
# 4 A         4
# 5 A         5
# 6 B         1
# 7 B         2
# 8 B         3
# 9 B         4
#10 B         5
```

Or with `complete`

```
tidyr::complete(group, val = seq(min(values$val), max(values$val)))
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily with `CJ` in `data.table`:

```
> setDT(df)
> df[CJ(group = group, val= values$val, unique = T), on = .(group, val)]
    group val
 1:     A   1
 2:     A   2
 3:     A   3
 4:     A   4
 5:     A   5
 6:     B   1
 7:     B   2
 8:     B   3
 9:     B   4
10:     B   5
```